# Create a method that will return a Lambda Expression that will be use in a lambda WHERE clause. Got error 1025

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4, lambda

I use Framework Entity 4 in my project.
I would like to create a function that will return an Expression
Nothing seem to work. I get this Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 1025.

Here is my Expression Method

```
   public Expression<Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>> GetLmbLang()
   {
       return (p => p.LangID == 1);
   }
```

I call the GetLmbLang method and get an error.

```
var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new {
                model,
                SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(repBase.GetLmbLang().Compile())
            });

            Response.Write("<pre>");
            Response.Write(((ObjectQuery)ViewModel).ToTraceString());
            Response.Write("</pre>");
```

If I write the expression directly in the WHERE clause , there is no problem.

```
var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new {
                model,
                SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(p => p.LangID == 1)
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: You get "an" error? What error do you get?

Comment: Error 7 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<cvc.Models.SupplierTypeText>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<cvc.Models.SupplierTypeText>' C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cvc\cvc\Controllers\SupplierController.cs 56 27 cvc

Comment: this error appear when I Compile with VS

Comment: Error 8 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<cvc.Models.SupplierTypeText>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cvc\cvc\Controllers\SupplierController.cs 56 27 cvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you invoke [Compile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) on your expression and you don't need to. You should just pass `repBase.GetLmbLang()` as the predicate to the Where method like this:

```
SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(repBase.GetLmbLang())
```

**EDIT:**

I think you've misunderstood a little about when you should use `Expression<Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>>` and when only `Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>`. 


Basically when you invoke *Where* method on `model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts` you are calling [*Enumerable.Where*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) Method with this signature (LINQ to Objects):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

But, by providing `Expression<Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>>` you actually meant [*Queryable.Where*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) which has this signature (LINQ to Entities):

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
)
```

Now what happened there is that when you code `model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(repBase.GetLmbLang())`
*SupplierTypeTexts* is populating from database by lazy loading and become a ready EntityCollection in memory for you to query so your **first solution** is to change the *GetLmbLang()* method accordingly:

```
public Func<SupplierTypeText, bool> GetLmbLang() {
       return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}
```

and then call it like this inside your anonymous class:

```
SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(repBase.GetLmbLang())
```

Your **second solution** would be to keep the *GetLmbLang()* method as it is now and actually change the way you create *SupType*:

```
var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new {
                model,
                SupType = _db.SupplierTypeTexts
                             .Where(repBase.GetLmbLang())
            });
```

**A Note on Provider Error 1205**:

This exception happens only when you are doing a projection with anonymous types and passing an `Expression<Func<...>>` inside like the code below:

```
var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new {
        SupType = _db.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(repBase.GetLmbLang())
});
```

If you remove the projection with anonymous type or if you keep the projection and get rid of the method that returns `Expression<Func<...>>` it will go away. Why this happens? I have no idea, it sounds like a provider bug to me. But one thing for sure is that theoretically it should works and there is absolutely nothing wrong with this code. That being said, feel free to start a new question and see what other guys have to say.

If you want to do so, then your question title should be something like this:
`Why am I getting Provider Error 1205 exception when I try to do a projection with anonymous type while passing in an Expression<Func<...>>?`

Comment: @Morteza, Very clean and usefull explanation as you always do. Thanks. One last thing. Why when I want to trace the SQL Query result with Response.Write(((ObjectQuery)ViewModel).ToTraceString()); I got this error.Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025. I would like to see the generated sql query.

Comment: No problem, please see my note on this above.